# How can I sum all numbers 1 from a string?

Tags: javascript, string, int

I need to sum all numbers 1 from a string!

For example: "00110010" = 1+1+1 = 3...

psum will receive this result and then I will check

```
if(psum >= 3){
  return person;
}
```

I need to find a way to solve it in javascript ES6 but I can't use any for, while or forEach loop,  unfortunately!!!

Could you help me?

Comment: Is this an assignment? Why can't you use those constructs? You don't have many options left except `reduce`. That's probably the point of the assignment.

Comment: HAH @Carcigenicate it sure is. Too bad this is a question about javascript :/ How did I wander in here?

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds like a class assignment with those restrictions.

Comment: Thank you @Will but I can't use a framework

Comment: I've tried to convert that string to int type, so I've got "110010", but what I need is the sum of number 1. I have no idea about what try again! @Herohtar

Answer (score 0):

Note that summing the numbers 1 comes down to *counting* the numbers 1, which is what the following solutions do in different ways:

#### With `match`

You could use a regular expression `/1/g`:

```js
var p = "00110010";
var psum = (p.match(/1/g) || []).length;

console.log(psum);
```

`match` returns an array of substrings that match with the pattern `1`. The `/` just delimit this regular expression, and the `g` means that all matches should be retrieved (global). The length of the returned array thus corresponds to the number of 1s in the input. If there are no matches at all, then `match` will return `null`, so that does not have a `.length` property. To take care of that `|| []` will check for that `null` (which is falsy in a boolean expression) and so `[]` will be taken instead of `null`.

#### With `replace`

This is a similar principle, but by matching non-1 characters and removing them:

```js
var p = "00110010";
var psum = p.replace(/[^1]/g, "").length;

console.log(psum);
```

`[^1]` means: a character that is not 1. `replace` will replace all matches with the second argument (empty string), which comes down to returning all characters that do not match. This is like a double negative: return characters that do *not* match with *not 1*. So you get only the 1s :-) `.length` will count those.

#### With `split`:

```js
var p = "00110010";
var psum = p.split("1").length - 1;

console.log(psum);
```

`split` splits the string into an array of substrings that do not have the given substring ("1"). So even if there are no "1" at all, you get one such substring (the whole string). This means that by getting the length, we should reduce it by 1 to get the number of 1s.

#### With a recursive function:

```js
var p = "00110010";
var count1 = p => p.length && ((p[0] == "1") + count1(p.slice(1)));
var psum = count1(p);

console.log(psum);
```

Here the function `count1` is introduced. It first checks if the given string *p* is empty. If so, `length` is zero, and that is returned. If not empty, the first character is compared with 1. This can be false or true. This result is converted to 0 or 1 respectively and added to a recursive call result. That recursive call counts the number 1s in the rest of the input (excluding the first character in which the 1s were already counted).

Comment: Thank you @trincot

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need clarification with one of the solutions.

Comment: It worked successfully.. I'm so grateful for your help!

Comment: Sure... I would like to understand!
Let me know how it works

Comment: I added explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the reduce() method.

```
let input = '00110010'
let array = input.split("").map(x => parseInt(x));

let sum = array.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return acc + val;
});

console.log(sum)
```

Comment: Be aware that if your string has 2 or 3, that those numbers are summed up as well. From the question I understood only numbers 1 should be added.

Comment: Ah, indeed @tricot. I may have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

In one statement:

```js
let psum = "00110010".split('').reduce((t, n) => {return t + parseInt(n)}, 0);

console.log(psum);
```